# Change password from database of a live site

Tags: php, fuelphp, fuelcms

I have an old project that is done in Fuel PHP and the site is live. The problem is that I forgot the password of the admin login. I am not able to reset it. I have the credentials of the Cpanel so, I wanted to directly change the password from the database. But, I am not able to do it. I cannot understand how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Login to your Cpanel. Go to database users table and put your new password inside password field.

If your password is md5 or bcrypt then go to google and search string to bcrypt or string to md5 you can findout lot of online website to make md5 or bcrypt password. Just copy them put inside password table and login successfully.

Bcrypt Generator : https://bcrypt-generator.com/

Comment: I tried with both the methods but it is not successful

Comment: what's your login credential ?